# Need help creating a report that will display a count of appointment types by month

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I am working on a school project using mySQL and C#. We are required to create a report that will count the number of a type of appointment and order it by month. i have added the code I use to populate the gatagridview. it currently lists the types of appointments and shows the count of each. it's the order by month part I am having issues with as I am still learning SQL. any help will be appreciated.

````
        {
            MySqlConnection con = DBHandler.getConnection();
            string com = $"SELECT type AS 'Appointment Type', COUNT(*) AS 'Number' FROM appointment GROUP BY type";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(com, con);
            con.Open();
            da.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }```
````

Comment: Add an `ORDER BY` to the end of your SQL statement.

Comment: the only problem with that is the database only has a date in mm:dd:yyyy format

Comment: You've provided no details about your table design, but it appears that you've designed it poorly. That format is not a date column, but a varchar column. If you use a proper date format for the column, you can use the date functions to retrieve portions of the dates like month and year.

Comment: I didn't design the database, it was provided by the course instructor. the column that contains the dates of the appointments is called 'start' and is a DateTime column

Comment: that's my bad, I for some reason assumed everyone had the database access lol. it's been a long year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you also need to group on the appointment month.  Assuming that the date field is called "appointmentDate", this would be the query:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM appointmentDate) appointmentMonth,
type AS 'Appointment Type', 
COUNT(*) AS 'Number' 
FROM appointment 
GROUP BY appointmentMonth, type
```